# why is my question closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

Why was this question closed: https://superuser.com/questions/223366/can-ping-ip-address-and-nslookup-hostname-but-cannot-ping-hostname-closed ? Please reopen it since it hasn't been fixed yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question was not closed.  It was migrated to another StackExchange site called ServerFault.  Here's the new link to your question:

https://serverfault.com/questions/214749/can-ping-ip-address-and-nslookup-hostname-but-cannot-ping-hostname

For future reference, questions regarding Server operating systems and enterprise-level networking are not appropriate for the SuperUser environment.  Please post such questions to ServerFault instead.  SuperUser is intended for questions about Workstation operating systems and Small Office/Home Office (SOHO) networks.

Comment: That leads immediately to the question why the hint and link that it is migrated isn't at the top of the page, but at the bottom

Answer (score 8):

If you look at the stated reason for close you will see that it was migrated over to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/214749/can-ping-ip-address-and-nslookup-hostname-but-cannot-ping-hostname).